# Badly resizing font

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

Although the font size is set to 1 rem, when changing the screen size, some letters are smaller than they should be. The font I am using is Bariol Regular from woff file. I am using Bootstrap with React on frontend.

On a higher resolution screen (e.g.: s is too small and e is too big):

[image]

On a lower resolution screen:

[image]

What can I do about it to fix this problem?

Comment: Try another font and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @SecretTimes, after changing the font the problem disappeared, but I can't leave it changed.

Comment: Did you try it by giving font-size in "px" instead of "rem" to check if it solves your problem?

Comment: @zainkhan Yes. That did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because of the font, changing it should fix this problem.

To prevent this, set some sort of min-font-size. This property does not exist, but you can use [CSS new clamp() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) to achieve this.

```css
p {
  font-size: clamp(12px, 5em, 20px);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some default text
</p>
```

This means, have at least 12px and maximum of 20px font size. So if you change the 5em to something like 1em, you should see the size for 1em.

This solution prevents the text from getting too small and becoming unreadable.

Comment: Please be aware that `clamp` does not work in MSIE at all: https://caniuse.com/?search=clamp

Comment: Of course it doesn't work on IE, it is a new feature and IE doesn't support any new features.

Comment: That is correct, but there are many MSIE users still out there (unfortunately) so its not uncommon you have to support those depending on your project. Your answer is totally fine, i just wanted to alert anyone who may come here that youll need something else if you want to support MSIE.